# Initialize members of a class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class with the following declaration:

```
class OrderBook {
        std::string OrderBookType;
        std::map<double, vector<float*>> OrderBookData;
        std::unordered_map<int, float*> OrderPool;
        
        public:
                OrderBook(string);
}
```

I have 2 questions regarding the class initialization:

1. I would like to specify the comparator for the **OrderBook** map based on **OrderBookType**.
   Is the following valid/good programming practice?

```
OrderBook::OrderBook(string bookType) {
        
        OrderBookType = bookType;
        
        if (bookType == 'B') {
                OrderBookData = std::map<float, vector<float*>, std::greater<float>>
        }
        else {
                OrderBookData = std::map<float, vector<float*>, std::less<float>>
        }

        OrderPool;
}
```

2. How do I initialize an empty map for **OrderPool**? To make sure **OrderPool** is an empty unordered map, do I have to do the following:

```
OrderPool = std::unordered_map<int, float*>()
```

or is `OrderPool;` sufficient?

Comment: You can specify your own comparator which uses a boolean value, and then calls the appropriate less or greater.

Comment: @ChrisMM Could you please give an example of how this is done? So the comparator will take in 3 INPUTS (float one, float two, std:string toggle)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To 1.**

No, it's not valid.

The types

```
std::map<float, vector<float*>, std::greater<float>>
```

and

```
std::map<float, vector<float*>, std::less<float>>
```

are different. You can't change the types at runtime.

IMHO the best approach is to create an own comparator that expects an argument and is passed to the constructor of the map (as mentionend in the comments of the question).

```
class Comp {
public:
    Comp(bool greater) : g(greater) {}
    bool operator()(double lhs, double rhs) const {
        if (g) return lhs > rhs;
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
private:
    bool g;
};

struct OrderBook {
        std::string OrderBookType;
        std::map<double, std::vector<float*>, Comp> OrderBookData;
        std::unordered_map<int, float*> OrderPool;
        
        public:
                OrderBook(const std::string &);
};

OrderBook::OrderBook(const std::string &bookType) : OrderBookType(bookType), OrderBookData(Comp(bookType == "B")) {}
```

**To 2.**

`std::unordered_map<int, float*> OrderPool;` will be initialized as empty unordered map. The line

```
OrderPool;
```

does nothing.

You don't need to (and technically speaking you can't) initialize it again. If you want to clear the map you can use [std::unordered_map<Key,T,Hash,KeyEqual,Allocator>::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/clear)

You could also create a new object and assign it with

```
OrderPool = std::unordered_map<int, float*>()
```

but I prefer

```
OrderPool.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. For 1, would you then recommend I initialize OrderBookData as an auto and then assign the correct object? So in my class declaration I would have auto OrderBookData. And then in the constructor, I would have OrderBookData = std::map<float, vector<float*>, std::less<float>>()?

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah No, that won't change anything. `auto` is not a dynamic type. The type is still deduced at compile time.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any advice on how I could initialize OrderBookData then? Must all members of a class be declared - could I introduce OrderBookData in the constructor of OrderBook (without being declared) and expect it to behave like a member?

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah You can use `std::variant`. I added an example.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "create an own comparator that expects an argument and is passed to the constructor of the map". Does the comparator take 3 arguments (where the 3rd is a std::string toggle)? A simple example will be very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VimellPresadYuvarajah I added an example.